# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:minimize

Tags: python, python-3.x, gurobi

I am trying to optimize the function but got stuck with this error

I have used **gurobi** and **objectiveset** function

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-17-afe6460fbdd9> in <module>
     72 
     73 
---> 74 m.setObjective(quicksum(c[i,j]*x[i,j]  for (i,j) in x),  "minimize")
     75 m.update()
     76 m.optimize()

   model.pxi in gurobipy.Model.setObjective()

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'minimize'
```

Answer (score 1):

On checking [the docs](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_model_setobjective.html), `setObjective` doesn't take a string, you pass [a defined constant](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_constants.html) for the "Objective sense" (which apparently is an `int` value) as the second argument. Change `'minimize'` to `gurobipy.GRB.MINIMIZE`.

Comment: Moreover  "minimize" is the default direction, so just not passing a second argument will suffice.